# Let $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac {z^{n+1}} {n(n+1)}$ be a power series. Show sum-function $g(z)$ is continuous on $|z|\le 1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac {z^{n+1}} {n(n+1)}$ be a power series.

I've shown that radius of convergence is $R=1$.

I've a theorem saying that the sum-function $g(z)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac {z^{n+1}} {n(n+1)}$ is continuous for $|z| < R$.

How can I show that $g(z)$ is continuous on the set $|z|\le 1$ ?

Comment: For $\left|z\right|=1$ it's not a geometric series. You can use Weierstrass M test to show uniform convergence. This implies continuity, as partial sums are continuous.

Comment: Why is it not a geometric series ? The absolute value of $$\mid \frac {z} {(n(n+1))^{\frac {1} {n+1}}} \mid^{n+1}$$ is less than 1 ?

Comment: Geometric series has terms $q^n$, where $q$ is *constant*, independent of $n$.

Comment: ahh thanks, do you also have a hint on how to prove $f^{'}(x) = -\log(1-x)$, where $f(x)$ is the restriction of $g(x)$ onto the real line.

Comment: Yes - series of derivatives of terms converges uniformly inside $(0,1)$, so we can differentiate the series "term by term", and use well-known expansion of logarithm. Then we need to handle endpoints separately. Let me know in case you need more hints.

Comment: I've shown that $R=1$ and I find the majorant series for $\frac {z^{n+1}} {n(n+1)}$ is $\frac 1 {n^2+n}$ given $|z|\le1$. This majorant series is convergent, which implies the original series is convergent for $|z|\le1$. However, what if I do the same with $|z| \le 2$ ? I can still get a convergent majorant series implying that the original series is convergent on $|z|\le 2$ ? This contradicts $R=1$ ?

Comment: You can't show that for $\left|z\right|>1$, as the series is divergent outside its circle of convergence. Note that for $\left|z\right|>1$ terms of the series are not even convergent to 0 - in fact, the grow unboundedly.

Comment: I've proved $$f(x) = \log(1-x)(1-x)+x$$ on $(-1,1)$. How can I show $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac 1 {n(n+1)} = 1$$ ? Can I use the continuity of $f$ ?

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer taking into account comments and answers to comments.

I suppose that you noticed that $$f(z)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac {z^{n+1}} {n(n+1)}$$ is the antiderivative of $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac {z^{n}} {n}=-\log (1-z)$$ So, integration by parts leads to $$f(z)=z+(1-z) \log (1-z)$$

Comment: How do I know $f(z) = z + (1-z)\log(1-z)$ is true ? The anti-derivative differs by a constant ? Also how can I use this to show $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac {1} {n(n+1)} = 1$ ?

Comment: Integrate by parts and do not forget the constant (as I did). Use partial fraction decomposition and $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac {1} {n(n+1)} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})=1$ since it is a beautiful telescoping series.

Comment: Yeah I know this Gauss trick, but I guess, since the question is last in the exercise it should be proved using the earlier steps ? Can I utilize that $f$ is continious on $[-1,1]$ and then say that $z+(1-z)\log(1-z)$ approximate $f(1)$ for $x \rightarrow 1$ ?